# Exception in Aplication start method -- JavaFx with Intellj

Tags: object, exception, javafx

I am trying to learn how to code with JavaFx but every time I try to create an object (ex.: WebView webview = new Webview();) I get this error:

ERROR-START{

> Exception in Application start method
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
>   java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
>   method    at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class
>   com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web.NGWebView (in unnamed module @0x7dab7530)
>   cannot access class com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup (in module
>   javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export
>   com.sun.javafx.sg.prism to unnamed module @0x7dab7530     at
>   java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)   at
>   java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)    at
>   java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:600)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     at AppL.start(AppL.java:8)  at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native
>   Method)   at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
>     ... 1 more Exception running application AppL

}ERROR-ENDING

I've tried to add: (I also added the PATH_TO_FX Path-variable)

--module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

to the run configurations VM-options but it only changed the error I had before this error. I tried to do this on Windows AND on Linux, neither works.

Intellj shows me that every thing works, but it doesn't.

I wanted to use netbeans or eclipse but I don't know how to add libraries to them.
That would helb me to.

Example code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AppL extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        WebView v = new WebView();
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Thanks to anyone who wants to help me, and who doesn't lauph on my english-scills

Comment: `WebView` is in the `javafx.web` module. Btw: please take a look at the question before posting it. The imho correct markup for the stacktrace would have been code markup, not a blockquote that doesn't preserve line breaks and doesn't use a monospaced font. Would have fixed this myself but now you've posted it it would be necessary to fix almost every line manually because of the line breaks being all over the place. Preferably copy&paste the stacktrace & use the features of the editor to convert it to a code block.

Comment: @fabian Thank you. I have just added "javafx.web" into VM options and it's working fine.